# Standard for writing chemical formulae and chemical names

Tags: discussion

As we'll be seeing a lot of chemical formulae, and since mathjax is available, we should define a standard way of representing chemical formulae in our posts.

I propose something like `\mathrm{formula}` as in

$\mathrm{H_2O}$

which is neat. Anybody feel fancier?

We also need to figure out how to write chemical names.
What do you think of something like `\textbf{chemical}` as in

$\textbf{diketone}$
?

**EDIT**

After writing a question using `\textbf{}` to wrap chemical names, I think that using the standard markdown `**text**` while using `\mathrm{}` for formulae command looks better.

Comment: I've filed a [request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130427/142977) for **mhchem** on the main meta…

Answer (score 8):

[Mathjax 2.0 supports](http://www.mathjax.org/2012/02/11/news/mathjax-v2-0-beta-now-available-on-cdn/) the [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) extension with stuff like `\ce{H2O}` etc. Either we bug the SE overlords to upgrade us, or we just copy the formatting of mhchem.

In the meantime, we can use the `\require{}` mathjax extension enabling switch. Eg:

```
 $\require{mhchem}$
 $\ce{HCl}$ dissociates in water as follows:
 $$\ce{H2O +HCl<=>H3O+ +Cl-}$$
```

Which yields:

[image: formula rendering]

Comment: SE is already using MathJax 2.0 as far as I know, it's only a matter of enabling this specific module.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nick T that particularly $\mathrm{}$ looks so different from the surrounding text that it becomes hard to read: the combination of the large size and roman font is ok for mathematics where most letters are lowercase and italicised, but not for bulky chemical formulas. That's why I'd prefer $\mathsf{}$ as I used [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/39/61), but it still looks a bit out of place. It also needs $\small$ added, because the letters are to tall otherwise. At any rate, I think one should use a unified $\newcommand{}$ at the beginning for plain-MathJax solutions.

Directly using html tags yields of course the most native look, but is IMO unacceptable because it's *really* awkward to type. I'd rather use Unicode characters then, like

> H₂SO₄ + H₂O  ⇌  HSO₄⁻ + H₃O⁺

Both have an improvised, unprofessional feel about them and lack proper environments for e.g. aligned equations.

mhchem with suitable settings would definitely be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm only throwing out a couple formulae, especially inline with text, I somewhat prefer using `<sup>` and `<sub>` as it just looks better and doesn't have some jarring transition.

e.g.

> CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2−</sup> compounds or simply CO<sub>2</sub> dissolved in water makes my enzyme work.

```
CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2&minus;</sup> compounds or simply CO<sub>2</sub> [...]
```

Comment: Or using equivalent LaTex notation.

Comment: @Khaloymes my point was that the LaTeX doesn't fit well with the rest of the text, and if using a couple formulae it sticks out like a sore thumb, (e.g. [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/79/mechanism-for-oxidation-of-arenes-via-permanganate))